# How to use webpack to implement Gmail's strategy of deferring JS parsing

Tags: javascript, performance, webpack, app-startup, deferred-loading

After reading

1. http://googlecode.blogspot.in/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html
2. http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-and-why-to-defer-parsing-of-javascript-in-a-webpage/

> Popularized by Google’s Gmail, the code is loaded within the comments of the page source. The browser will not parse it assuming it is nothing but comments, and when needed you can find the DOM element for the comments, strip out the comment blocks and run the code using the eval() method.

Is there any way in Webpack currently that allows such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader). Or you can use [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) to load the raw content of js file, and `eval` it by yourself in demand.